# calculate the average of multiple curves

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `203559x2` which corresponds to a data of discharges curves of a battery. Knowing that each charge has about 3622 points(but it is not a fixed value), at the end I have 56 curves. I want to make an average of each 10 curves, and after that I want to overload those average curves to compare their evolutoin.

what I tried to do is to reshape the data so to have each discharge curve in a column, and than make a mean of the columns.

here is an example of what I did:

M is a matrix `203559x2`

```
X= reshape(M(:,1),[], 56);
Y= reshape(M(:,2),[], 56);

n=10;
for i =1:size(M,2)
    X10=mean(X(:,(1+n:2*n),2, 'omitnan');
    Y10=mean(Y(:,(1+n:n+n),2, 'omitnan');
    n=n+n
end
```

But I'm missing something.
I have another table `M_indx` is a matrix `56x2` where I have the start line and the end line of the data for each curve, but I don't know how I can use it to write this script.

any help is welcome

Comment: We will very welcomely help you if you show what you tried and tell us why it did not work. We will very non-welcomely downvote you if you expect us to write it for you

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. As your question stands, it is very difficult to determine exactly what your inputs and desired outputs are.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several mistakes there, so I'm not sure which one is causing the problem:

1. 203559 rows of `M` are not divisible to 56 columns. `reshape` won't invent new values for you, so `M` must be precisely a multiple of 56. Also, if we take the closest value 203560 which *is* a multiple of 56, we get 3635 rows and not 3622 as you wrote. You better check again your data to see you are not missing anything.
2. You `for` loop is overwriting `X10` and `Y10` on every loop. In order to save the mean from all iterations you have to use the iterator of the loop - `i` for indexing the output variables `X10` and `Y10`.
3. You miss a closing `)` on every calling to the `mean` function.
4. At the end of the loop, you write `n = n+n` which doubles the number of columns to take the mean of in the next iteration, while you wrote you want to take them in batches of 10.
5. Not sure if this how you want it - but you start from column 11, not 1 (you start `n` from 10, not 0).

Here is a fixed version of your code:

```
X = reshape(M(:,1),[], 56);
Y = reshape(M(:,2),[], 56);
X10 = zeros(size(X,1),6);
Y10 = zeros(size(X,1),6);
n = 10;
for k = 1:n:size(X,2)
    c = (k+9)/n; % column for output
    X10(:,c) = mean(X(:,k:min(k+n-1,size(X,2))),2, 'omitnan');
    Y10(:,c) = mean(Y(:,k:min(k+n-1,size(X,2))),2, 'omitnan');
end
```

It takes the mean of 10 columns each time and put it in one column in `X10` and `Y10`. So `X10(:,1)` is the mean of `X(:,1:10)`, `X10(:,2)` is the mean of `X(:,11:20)` and so on, and the same for `Y10`.

This still doesn't solve problem 1 above, that you have to figure out with your data.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

Reshape will not work as you have stated:

> "each charge has ***about*** 3622 points"  *(emphasis mine)*

As using reshape would only work for a uniform number of points for each curve.

---

### Solution

The process of reshaping could to approximated by writing into columns of a larger matrix and filling empty entries with `nan` (essentially adding `nan` values to each column to make them all the same length)

```
sz = max(diff(M_indX,[],2))+1; % find max num of points across all curves
X=nan(sz,size(M_indX,1));
Y=nan(sz,size(M_indX,1));
for ii = 1:size(M_indX,1)
  iXs = M_indX(ii,1); % current curve ind X start
  iXe = M_indX(ii,2); % current curve ind X end
  X( 1:(iXe-iXs+1) ,ii) = M(iXs:iXe,1); 
  Y( 1:(iXe-iXs+1) ,ii) = M(iXs:iXe,2);
end
```

This code creates `X` and `Y` matrices initalised with `nan` The populates them by looping through each curve and writing its data into each column, leaving `nan` values where there are less data points for the current curve than `sz`, the number of points in the curve with the most points.

This workaround is compatible with `mean` due to the usage of the `'omitnan'` flag.

The other problems in the code are addressed in the answer by EBH